# Best practice - Migration between database in AzureSQL paas

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, sql-server-data-migration-assistant

I'm working on `azure SQL paas` platform.
Occasionally, I have to migrate data between databases.

As you know there you need to define login and user for cross query connection.
My question is:
What is the best practice for migration task between DB?
I've got this kind of jobs from time to time and as of now I'm import and exporting the data using csv.

I'm familiar with:

1. Data factory
2. Elastic job
3. Power automate.

Would it be possible to define a login and a user just for migrating between databases?

many thanks

Comment: More details would be helpful, such as: how much data (roughly speaking), if it's always from a single Table, if it's always from the same Table(s), if it's being migrated to the same *structured* Table(s), etc. Are both databases on the same server? Is this a SQL Server instance on an Azure VM, or an Azure SQL Server instance?

Comment: Hey, regarding your questions:  how much data? preferably no limit, now i am using csv so there is a limit to the file size.  if it's always from the same Table(s) ? it's not always from the same table. Are both databases on the same server? Most of the time the data is in the same server or at least in the same tenant. The SQL server is azure sql PAAS. so  you cannot link the two db straight forward. Thanks for your help